# Is there a way to access a class's members where when acessing you use a string instead of class name

Tags: c#, class, reflection

**Im looking to use some reflection to access all the members in a class and get their values.** This is the class's. I always initialize the "Championsids" class. (I know there is a lot of code but its quite straight forward).

```
        public class ChampionIds
        {
            public string type;
            public string format;
            public string version;
            public Data data;
        }

        public class Data
        {
            public Champions Aatrox;
            public Champions Ahri;
            public Champions Akali;
            public Champions Alistar;
            public Champions Amumu;
            public Champions Anivia;
            public Champions Annie;
            public Champions Ashe;
            public Champions AurelionSol;
            public Champions Azir;
            public Champions Bard;
            public Champions Blitzcrank;
            public Champions Brand;
            public Champions Braum;
            public Champions Caitlyn;
            public Champions Camille;
            public Champions Cassiopeia;
            public Champions Chogath;
            public Champions Corki;
            public Champions Darius;
            public Champions Diana;
            public Champions Draven;
            public Champions DrMundo;
            public Champions Ekko;
            public Champions Elise;
            public Champions Evelynn;
            public Champions Ezreal;
            public Champions FiddleSticks;
            public Champions Fiora;
            public Champions Fizz;
            public Champions Galio;
            public Champions Gangplank;
            public Champions Garen;
            public Champions Gnar;
            public Champions Gragas;
            public Champions Graves;
            public Champions Hecarim;
            public Champions Heimerdinger;
            public Champions Illaoi;
            public Champions Irelia;
            public Champions Ivern;
            public Champions Janna;
            public Champions JarvanIV;
            public Champions Jax;
            public Champions Jayce;
            public Champions Jhin;
            public Champions Jinx;
            public Champions Kalista;
            public Champions Karma;
            public Champions Karthus;
            public Champions Kassadin;
            public Champions Katarina;
            public Champions Kayle;
            public Champions Kennen;
            public Champions Khazix;
            public Champions Kindred;
            public Champions Kled;
            public Champions KogMaw;
            public Champions Leblanc;
            public Champions LeeSin;
            public Champions Leona;
            public Champions Lissandra;
            public Champions Lucian;
            public Champions Lulu;
            public Champions Lux;
            public Champions Malphite;
            public Champions Malzahar;
            public Champions Maokai;
            public Champions MasterYi;
            public Champions MissFortune;
            public Champions MonkeyKing;
            public Champions Mordekaiser;
            public Champions Morgana;
            public Champions Nami;
            public Champions Nasus;
            public Champions Nautilus;
            public Champions Nidalee;
            public Champions Nocturne;
            public Champions Nunu;
            public Champions Olaf;
            public Champions Orianna;
            public Champions Pantheon;
            public Champions Poppy;
            public Champions Quinn;
            public Champions Rammus;
            public Champions RekSai;
            public Champions Renekton;
            public Champions Rengar;
            public Champions Riven;
            public Champions Rumble;
            public Champions Ryze;
            public Champions Sejuani;
            public Champions Shaco;
            public Champions Shen;
            public Champions Shyvana;
            public Champions Singed;
            public Champions Sion;
            public Champions Sivir;
            public Champions Skarner;
            public Champions Sona;
            public Champions Soraka;
            public Champions Swain;
            public Champions Syndra;
            public Champions TahmKench;
            public Champions Taliyah;
            public Champions Talon;
            public Champions Taric;
            public Champions Teemo;
            public Champions Thresh;
            public Champions Tristana;
            public Champions Trundle;
            public Champions Tryndamere;
            public Champions TwistedFate;
            public Champions Twitch;
            public Champions Udyr;
            public Champions Urgot;
            public Champions Varus;
            public Champions Vayne;
            public Champions Veigar;
            public Champions Velkoz;
            public Champions Vi;
            public Champions Viktor;
            public Champions Vladimir;
            public Champions Volibear;
            public Champions Warwick;
            public Champions Xerath;
            public Champions XinZhao;
            public Champions Yasuo;
            public Champions Yorick;
            public Champions Zac;
            public Champions Zed;
            public Champions Ziggs;
            public Champions Zilean;
            public Champions Zyra;
        }

        public class Champions
        {
            public string version;
            public string id;
            public string key;
            public string name;
            public string title;
            public string blurb;
            public Dictionary<string, int> info;
            public Dictionary<string, string> image;
            public List<string> tags;
            public string partype;
            public Dictionary<string, double> stats;
        }
```

When i initialize it values are automatically assigned to all the members. That all works fine

```
ChampionIds championIds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChampionIds>(json2); //Assignment works perfect!
```

And now i can access all the values as so. Just for an example of usage

```
Console.WriteLine(championIds.data.Aatrox.id);
Console.WriteLine(championIds.data.Aatrox.key);

Console.WriteLine(championIds.data.AurelionSol.version);
Console.WriteLine(championIds.data.AurelionSol.title);
```

But the problem is i want to get all the different champions **keys** and **names** into a Dictionary. So something like this.

```
Dictionary<string, string> ChampIdDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
ChampIdDict.Add(championIds.data.Aatrox.key, championIds.data.Aatrox.name);
```

And i want to do this for each champion. For an example like this

```
Dictionary<string, string> ChampIdDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
ChampIdDict.Add(championIds.data.Aatrox.key, championIds.data.Aatrox.name);
ChampIdDict.Add(championIds.data.Ahri.key, championIds.data.Ahri.name);
ChampIdDict.Add(championIds.data.Akali.key, championIds.data.Akali.name);
//and so on
```

But i dont want to make 100 lines in my code of this way. So i iterate through all members and get their names easily with this code

```
FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Data).GetFields();
foreach (var field in fields)
{
     Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
}
```

And the result is this

```
Aatrox
Ahri
Akali
Alistar
Amumu
Anivia
//and so on
```

How do i make it so i can do this

```
FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Data).GetFields();
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inserting champion = " + field.Name + " into the dictionary");
    string key = championIds.data.(field.Name).key;
    string name = championIds.data.(field.Name).name;
    ChampIdDict.Add(key, name)
}
```

The result is that i simple get the champion id from a website and i say
string returnedChampionId = //from website ex. 266
string championName = ChampIdDict["266"];

Thanks for reading. Hope you can recommend something

Comment: instead class `Data` use `Dictionary<string, Champions>` ...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what that has anything to do with my question. Edit: Btw i cant do that already tested it. I get the input from JSON Deserializing so it basically has to be like that

Comment: @BjørnDrachmann You need to do this with a dictionary.

Comment: I can try with a Dictionary if you say so. But i get it from some JSON with the Newtonsoft library so i dont know if that will work. But thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get the value from each field and cast it to the appropriate type. Then you can access the inner properties

```
Data actualDataObject = // whereever you get it from
Dictionary<string, string> ChampIdDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Data).GetFields();
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    Champions temp = (Champions)field.GetValue(actualDataObject);
    string key = temp.key;
    string name = temp.name;
    ChampIdDict.Add(key, name)
}
```

In linq this could look something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> ChampIdDict = (from field in fields
                                    let temp = (Champions)field.GetValue(actualDataObject)
                                    select new {key = temp.key, name = temp.name})
                                   .ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.name);
```

Comment: This code worked. Thank you! Instead of the GetValue(actualDataObject) i used GetValue(championIds.data)